# Reconstructing avro Object from a Struct

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Kafka Connect to process messages from my Kafka Topic and when I receive a SinkRecord that contains an Avro message, the value I get is of Type "Struct" which is something that specific to Kafka Connect "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct" however, Im more interested in getting the specific Object that this Struct represents (e.g. a 'Customer' object which has all the getters/setters i would like to see)

Is there an easy way to map the "Struct" object back to the "Customer" object using Kafka Connect?

Comment: Are you using the Schema Registry? If so, you'd want to import or look at the AvroData class used in Confluent's AvroConverter

Comment: @OneCricketeer  Thanks a lot that really did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Confluent AvroData class, there's [fromConnectData](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/ee48518e04de3c7cfaaa80c0edde0eb106fc7449/avro-data/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/avro/AvroData.java#L335-L340) that does just that.

Comment: What if I have a String representation of the Struct? Like `Struct{ABC=2}`. How can I recreate the Struct Object from it with the Avro libs?

Comment: @Dopele Avro library doesn't parse strings; you'll need to do that yourself. I'd recommend finding the source of the data before it was toString'd